# Mouse input and z-axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
void OnMouseDrag() {
        float distance = transform.position.z - Camera.main.transform.position.z;
        Vector3 pos = Input.mousePosition;
        pos.z = distance;

        Vector3 mousePosition = new Vector3(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z);
        Vector3 objPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePosition);
        transform.position = objPosition;

    }
```

This is the code snippet help me to move the object on mouse drag. It is moving object on mouse drag in x axis while z axis movement is not working correctly using mouse. I basically want to move the object on x and **z-Axis** using mouse Input.
What is wrong h**ow can i get z position from the mouse input in order to move the object on z axis correctly**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you casting ray to your object it is being calculated multiple times so it returns your ball position when its not being move a real deal you can try something like this

```
void OnMouseDrag() {

    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

    Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * 10, Color.yellow);
    Debug.Log(ray);

    RaycastHit hit;

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, Camera.main.farClipPlane))
    {

        if (hit.transform.gameObject.name == "CameraElasticPoint")
        {
            return;
        }
        else{
            transform.position = new Vector3(hit.point.x,hit.transform.position.y+1, hit.point.z);
            hitPoint = Input.mousePosition;
        }

    }
}
```

what it will do it will ignore your objects and works only on other hit info which would be your floor or any other surface you are trying to drag your object along and it will drag your object on X and Z axis taking the Y position of the Floor so it will always remain on top of the floor or any other surface collider on 
let me know if it works
Good day

Comment: Thanks Anwar you help me early in the morning. I were hanged in this problem from last 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend going through the Unity Tutorial here:

http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/survival-shooter-project

It might give you some ideas on how to solve the problem of x/z plane movement with the mouse.

Comment: this is along tutorial which phase contain the input?

Comment: Its not that long, I finished it in a couple hours, You'll learn a lot. It's really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

No. screenpointtoray is very unnecessary here, you just need to say that pos.z is equal to pos.x....

like so...

```
Vector3 pos = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(Input.mousePosition - dragOrigin);
        pos.z = pos.x;
        Vector3 move = new Vector3(0, pos.y * dragSpeed, pos.z * -dragSpeed);
```

always a pleasure x